# Как сделать меню настройки последовательного порта, желательно в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pyserial

Уже неделю пытаюсь разобраться как сделать это меню с комбобоксами, честно говоря - даже удивлён тому, что нигде нет примеров именно настройки портов, именно выбора параметров в самой программе, а не создание порта с заранее заданными значениями того же порта, битрейта, четности, и прочего. Может плохо ищу, может всё настолько просто, что это не требует объяснений, но видимо я слишком глуп, чтоб это понять. Серьёзно, за всю неделю видел только один пример программы на питоне, в которой была настройка порта, но все комментарии там на китайском, криво переведённом на английский, да и написана она видимо на более старой версии как Питона, так и PySerial, ибо её копия тупо не запускается, ругаясь на неправильное написание и отсутствие модулей. Уже даже задавал похожий вопрос тут, но внятного ответа так и не получил, только что-то вроде "так это ж переменные, меняй как хочешь". Как их менять-то?

Чего пытаюсь добиться: запускаю программу, открывается окно, в нём уже выбираю из комбобоксов порт, битрейт, тип четности, кол-во битов в пакете, кол-во стопбитов и уже после этого отправляю сообщения из полей ввода. Интерфейс уже есть

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У вас задача состоит из двух частей: 1 - создать графический интерфейс с нужными полями, 2 - использовать данные из полей для настройки соединения. Сначала сосредоточьтесь на 1 части, потом уже переходите ко второй.

Comment: Интерфейс уже есть, надо было это тут указать, согласен

Comment: Ну вот. Теперь допустим у вас есть кнопка соединения. Пишите для нее функцию-обработчик, в ней из полей получаете данные, типа `port = entry_port.get()`, и т.д., по этим данным подключаетесь. В целом, если бы вы привели свой код, было бы понятнее как вам помочь.

Comment: Ок, порт и битрейт видно, там действительно просто значения достаточно взять, но что с четностью, например? Она же, если я правильно понял из доков, там записывается, например, не просто None, a PARITY_NONE. Код сейчас попробую сократить, чтоб сюда добавить, просто там окно довольно большое, около двухсот строчек вышло

Answer (score 1):

В целом задача ну очень легкая. чтобы сделать окно используй следующий код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

root.geometry("500x500")
```

чтобы создать комбобокс

```
combobox_values = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'] #сюда вставляете нужные параметры

combobox = ttk.Combobox(root, values = combobox_values, state = "readonly")
```

чтобы не париться с получениям значения используйте StringVar(для сторки) или IntVar(для числа) для выбраного значения

```
combobox_value = StringVar()
# или
combobox_value = IntVar()
# чтобы задать значение по умолчанию используйте параметр value как для StringVar так и для IntVar
combobox_value = StringVar(value='apple')
```

полноценный код для создания комбобокса:

```
combobox_values = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
combobox_value = StringVar(value = combobox_values[0])
combobox = ttk.Combobox(root, values = combobox_values, textvariable = combobox_value, state = "readonly")
combobox.pack() #размещения в окне, можно также использовать grid или place 
#подробнее тут: https://www.delftstack.com/de/tutorial/tkinter-tutorial/tkinter-geometry-managers/
```

чтобы получить значение используйте метод .get()

```
combobox_value.get() # -> "apple"
```

полностью код будет выглядеть так:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

root.geometry("500x500")

combobox_values = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
combobox_value = StringVar(value = combobox_values[0])
combobox = ttk.Combobox(root, values = combobox_values, textvariable = combobox_value, state = "readonly")
combobox.pack()

def get_combobox_value():
    print(combobox_value.get())

button = Button(text = "Подтвердить", command = get_combobox_value)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

результат
[image: видео]

добавление значений

```
def add_combobox_value(new_value):
    values = list(combobox.cget('values'))
    values.append(new_value)
    combobox.configure(values = values)
```

Comment: Так интерфейс-то сам у меня есть, как .get пользоваться вроде как тоже разобрался, основная проблема в том, что я не понимаю как сам последовательный порт туда впихнуть и с помощью тех же комбобоксов настраивать. Какие-то значения там можно просто взять и использовать сразу (те же порт и битрейт), а вот остальные, вроде той же четности или количества битов в пакете вроде как принимают другие совсем значения, например не 8, а EIGHTBIT, нет Odd, а PARITY_ODD

Comment: чтобы добавить значение, используйте .configure(values = ["новые значения"])

Comment: обновил ответ, добавил функцию для апдейта

Comment: Да проблема не в этом. Как преобразовать значения из комбобоксов в те, которые сможет понять PySerial? Да и как правильно сам порт оттуда вписать?

Comment: можно сделать словарь, и переобразовывать данные

Comment: dictionary = {"8" : "EIGHTBIT", "Odd" : "PARITY_ODD"}

Comment: Это попробовал, какие-то значения он принимает, на каких-то выдаёт следующую ошибку, как пример:
ValueError: Not a valid byte size: 'EIGHTBITS'
(Там таки именно с s на конце, только что перепроверил)

Comment: @RandomName у вас там скорее всего константы из библиотеки, укажите в словаре сами константы вместо строк, без кавычек: `dictionary = {"8" : EIGHTBIT, "Odd" : PARITY_ODD}`